# Impossibility of deriving the Born Rule?

Tags: mathematical-physics, random, quantum-mechanics

### Background

Let's say I have a physical system. When a measurement happens we apply the Born rule to say which outcome is likely.

1. Now, while a lot of physicists are of the opinion the measurement is a [non-unitary transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156533/why-arent-transformations-caused-by-measurements-unitary).
2. They are also of the opinion that the whole system undergoes unitary transformation (while a sub-system does not).

This seems to mean to me that the real problem is getting the apparatus to be of the same initial state in both experiments. If one does so then one can evade the Born rule.

### Heuristically:

If we consider the physical system alone:

$$ |\text{system in A} \rangle + |\text{system in B}\rangle \to |\text{system  in A}\rangle$$

However, when we consider the measuring apparatus as well:

$$ (|\text{system in A} \rangle + |\text{system in B}\rangle) \otimes |\text{apparatus in C} \rangle  \to |\text{system in A} \rangle \otimes |\text{apparatus in D} \rangle  $$

Note in the first equation the we assume we say the measurement is non-unitary transformation in the second we say the complete system obeys unitarity.

### Question

If the above notion is correct the Born rule seems to be an artefact of some notion of randomness of when (the time) the measurement is being done. Is there any physical system within which we time the measurement such that this possibility can be ruled out?

Comment: The second isn't unitary. The transformation should more or less look like $$(|\text{system in A} \rangle + |\text{system in B}\rangle) \otimes |\text{apparatus in C} \rangle  \to\\ |\text{system in A} \rangle \otimes |\text{apparatus in D} \rangle + |\text{system in B} \rangle \otimes |\text{apparatus in E} \rangle$$

Comment: I think most physicists believe that the measurement procedure is unitary time evolution. As you remark, it obviously isn't unitary if you only consider the system that is observed, but a measurement is a drastic incursion by the measurement apparatus. Since physicists believe that quantum mechanics is "correct" (with the usual philosophical baggage attached), the process of measuring should also be described by the rules of quantum mechanics, as such it should be given by unitary time evolution of the very complicated composite system.

Comment: @Hurkyl I used the word heuristic but I had the "NOT" gate equivalent in mind which is the "CNOT" gate and they achieve so by ancilla qubits

Comment: (cont.) The "measurement procedure" describes what happens when a quantum state interacts with a "classical state". If you believe that reality obeys quantum mechanics, then such a scenario does not actually exist (since the "classical state" must actually be a quantum state), what we call the measurement process is then not a fundamental aspect of the theory itself, but an emergent process that must follow from the other rules of the theory.

Comment: @s.harp I've heard this idea before as well. What is the name of this idea? The closest thing I know of is Bohr's correspondence principle

Comment: I believe this perspective is (or used to be) called the many worlds interpretation of QM. There is a book edited by DeWitt about this subject, although it may be old at this point.